# display a dialog when the location in the map is not found

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to display a dialog when the location in the map is not found. but always force close if the location is sought is not found .. is there something wrong with my code ??
please help thank you very much
Best Regards

```
public void onSearch(View view) {
    String location = edit.getText().toString();

    List<Address> addressList = null;


    if(!location.equals("")) {

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Address address = addressList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Posisi"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
        if(address!=null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Location Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Location Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        }else if(location.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "location null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check if addressList is null or size is 0. then, Show a dialog.**

```
public void onSearch(View view) {
    String location = edit.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressList = null;
    if(!location.equals("")) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if((addressList == null) || (addressList != null && addressList.size == 0)){
            //Show a dialog here;
            return;
        }
        Address address = addressList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Posisi"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
        if(address!=null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Location Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Location Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        }
   }else if(location.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "location null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }    
}
```

Comment: thanks to your help I already solved problems . Once Again thanks for the help  ^_^

Comment: @alfianvian Great. But you can upvote it bcoz my answer is right. :)